# Is there a CSS nth child reset

Tags: css

After much searching and reading the only way to reset an nth seems to be per my example below. Without the `:nth-child(1)` the rules will persist through all media queries.

Example, which would be common, is a flexbox list with numerous rows of elements. At mobile 2 across, at tablet 3 and desktop 4. I want to set left margin for all but first element of the row which would be dynamic based on viewport.

No mention of a reset in:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Is there a better approach?

```
.example {
    width: calc((100% - 30px) /2);
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 12px 6px;
    &:not(:nth-child(2n+1)) {
        background-color: blue;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        width: calc((100% - 30px) / 3);
        &:not(:nth-child(1)) {
            background-color: transparent;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        &:not(:nth-child(3n+1)) {
            background-color: red;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
        width: calc((100% - 90px) /6);
        &:not(:nth-child(1)) {
            background-color: transparent;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        &:not(:nth-child(6n+1)) {
            background-color: green;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reset that I know of. The combo of `:not()` and `:nth-child()` is a little messy. Based on how I'm reading your code I'd recommend doing a range instead. Check out [http://nthmaster.com/](http://nthmaster.com/) for some options that may help

Comment: @couchwood thanks. The problem, as per my example, is that margin left would be different if there are 2, 3 or 6 columns (based on media queries) and as such range wouldn't solve the issue. The problem is that without the reset I'm using the margin of the former MQ would still be active. I suspect I'ms tuck with this or using JS